# Toshiba laptop, Windows 7, bitLocker password problem

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, bitlocker

I have previously installed Windows 7, Ultimate and used bitLocker for my drive D, after some time, my windows had problems with virus, and I had to reinstall, but as it didn't work properly, I formatted C: drive where windows was installed, and tried to install back the Windows 7, but now it is asking for the bitLocker key, which I don't remember, but it is giving the bitLocker key identification number, which is: AC3E0122-C59F-4BD8-8EA1-B2C3A5016FAA.
Can anyone help with this issue?
thanx

Answer (score 0):

I would follow this document, but if it does not work, you may simply be out of luck. The point of it is encrypted so that it cannot be easily broken, or broken at all.

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-security/cant-access-bitlocker-encrypted-external-hard/19f28028-eace-4878-b5e5-8cd78c19f6f3

Answer (score 0):

> **What is a BitLocker Drive Encryption
>   startup key or PIN?**
>
> When you use BitLocker Drive
>   Encryption, you need a BitLocker Drive
>   Encryption startup key or personal
>   identification number (PIN) to start
>   your computer.
>
> BitLocker stores its own encryption
>   and decryption keys in a hardware
>   device called the Trusted Platform
>   Module (TPM) security hardware, which
>   is a special microchip in some newer
>   computers that supports advanced
>   security features. The keys are not
>   stored on the computer’s hard disk.
>   The TPM must be accessible by the
>   basic input/output system (BIOS)
>   during startup. When you start your
>   computer, BitLocker will get these
>   keys from the TPM automatically.
>
> If your computer was not manufactured
>   with TPM version 1.2 or higher, you
>   can create a BitLocker startup key
>   using a USB flash drive to store the
>   encryption keys and decryption keys.
>   You will have to insert the flash
>   drive each time you start the
>   computer.
>
> In addition to the option of creating
>   a startup key, you have the option of
>   creating a startup personal
>   identification number (PIN). You can
>   create either the startup key or the
>   startup PIN, but not both. The startup
>   PIN can be any number that you choose
>   from 4 to 20 digits in length. The PIN
>   is stored on your computer. You will
>   have to type the PIN each time you
>   start the computer.
>
> You can only create a startup key or
>   PIN when you turn on BitLocker for the
>   first time. After you create the
>   startup key or PIN, you can use the
>   BitLocker Manage Keys feature to
>   change the PIN. You can also make
>   additional copies of the startup key
>   to use in case you lose the original.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/What-is-a-BitLocker-Drive-Encryption-startup-key-or-PIN